# Calling ` google.accounts.id.prompt` returns error 400 for browser that is does not have a google session

Tags: google-signin, google-api-js-client, google-identity

When calling `prompt()` from a browser that has a google session

```
google.accounts.id.initialize({
    client_id: MY_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    auto_select: false,
    callback: handleCredentialResponse
})
google.accounts.id.prompt()
```

I get to see the one-tap showing up and a subsequent call to my `handleCredentialResponse` callback.

But, If I try from a different browser session (clean chrome session) that is not logged into google I see a 400 error when the js library tries to contact google:

```
https://accounts.google.com/gsi/status?client_id=MY_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID&as=...
```

The actual response is

```
400. That’s an error.

The server cannot process the request because it is malformed. 
It should not be retried. That’s all we know.
```

What do I need to do in order to show the 'sign-in with google' popup in such a case?